# Alt Text in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to fetch the alt text for image outside the loop which i have uploaded on media.I have tried following code but it is working only on loop

```
<?php $imageID = get_field('THIS IS YOUR FIELD NAME FOR THE IMAGE'); ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'full' ); ?>
<?php $alt_text = get_post_meta($imageID , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the alt text of one specific image? Then it should work like this:

```
<?php
$image_id = //your image ID
$alt = get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
echo $alt;
?>
```